# Merge Twitter and Instagram API Results and Order by Date

Tags: php, twitter, instagram, instagram-api

I am using the https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php Twitter API PHP wrapper and the https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API#authenticate-user-oauth2 Instagram API PHP wrapper, both are functioning and displaying the results as I intended. However, what I was hoping to accomplish was merging both results and ordering them by date, newest to oldest, and displaying them in a masonry fashion. My PHP isn't the strongest so I am really just looking for guidance to get me on the right path. The code now is pretty basic, basically a couple of foreach loops, one for Instagram and one for Twitter a majority of the work is handled by the wrappers by passing in the appropriate keys/tokens.

For Twitter each tweet has 'created_at' and that is the very first piece of data returned:

`[ { "created_at":"Wed Mar 18 19:33:49 +0000 2015"`

Then based on the wrapper I am using I can access it within my foreach loop by doing:

`$tweetDate = date('F j, Y', strtotime($tweets->created_at));`

Instagram uses created_time and based on the wrapper I can access it using:

`echo date('F j, Y', $entry->created_time);`

Hopefully that helps but please let me know if you'd like to see more.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that that the results of both API calls contain some date key/value that can be used to sort the data. You can [merge the results](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) in `data` variable (array) and then use:

```
function dateSort($a, $b)
{
    return strtotime($a) >= strtotime($b);
}

usort($data, "dateSort");
```

The format of `data` should be something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => '2015-04-09',
    [1] => '2015-03-15',
    [2] => '2015-04-06'
)
```

The output would be

```
Array
(
    [0] => '2015-03-15',
    [1] => '2015-04-06',
    [2] => '2015-04-09'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't paste in samples of your data, but since you mentioned `foreach` loops I'll assume you've got two arrays of results that you want to merge and sort...

For merging nested arrays, you'll want either `array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2)` or `array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2)`.  The difference between the two is how they handle duplicate keys in the two arrays: `array_merge_recursive()` will preserve both values for a duplicate key in a nested array, wheres `array_replace_recursive()` will overwrite the values of `$array1` with the values in `$array2` for duplicate keys.

For example:

```
$array1 = ['key1' => 'original value', 'key2' => 'value2'];
$array2 = ['key1' => 'overlapped value', 'key3' => 'value3'];
$mergeResult = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
$replaceResult = array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

`$mergeResult` will look like this:

```
[
    'key1' => [
        'original value', 
        'overlapped value'
    ],
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
]
```

`$replaceResult` will look like this:

```
[
    'key1' => 'overlapped value',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
]
```

It's up to you which is more appropriate for your application.

If you're working with nested arrays, then to sort the array resulting from your merge, you'll want to use `usort()`.  Here's a simplified example that assumes that the value you want to sort by is 1 level deep in a nested array:

```
function sortByDate($a, $b) {
    return $a['date'] - $b['date'];
}

usort($array1, 'sortByDate');
```

Here are docs for [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php), [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php), and [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: Sorry that I did not give examples of the data. For Twitter each tweet has 'created_at' and that is the very first piece of data returned: 

`[
   {
      "created_at":"Wed Mar 18 19:33:49 +0000 2015",`

Then based on the wrapper I am using I can access it within my foreach loop by doing:

`$tweetDate = date('F j, Y', strtotime($tweets->created_at));`

Instagram uses created_time and based on the wrapper I can access it using:

`echo date('F j, Y', $entry->created_time);`

Hopefully that helps but please let me know if you'd like to see more. Thank you!